# How to get a PID for a specific app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I get ProcessInfo of a particular app (Not the same app/process)? I know that "NSProcessInfo" gives the details of the current process. But I would like to know is there any way to get the info of particular process say for example "Mail". If Mail is running in background, how can I get the info of it?

P.S: Requirement is on a jail-broken IPhone.

Thanks,
Prathap.

Comment: A very good tutorial can be found in the following link.
http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/a-simple-objectie-c-class-for-checking-if-a-specific-process-is-running/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a jail-broken phone you should be able to use the system command together with ps to get the pid on any running processes.  [This link describes in detail how to use the system command.](http://maccoder.blogspot.com/2007/04/interacting-with-command-line-in.html)